# Login Validation - Won't Connect To DB While Connecting In Other Scripts Works Fine

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I'm having several issues with my login coding, the biggest one being that I get a database connection error every time I run it. I don't know why because everything worked fine the first time I tried it out and connecting to the database any other time works no problem. Left it alone to work on some other stuff and now it doesn't seem to want to work all of a sudden.

#### Validation Scripts

I did not write these, I found them on w3schools.in and they were the only scripts the even worked out of the 20 or so I tried. Well, to begin with. The only thing I changed was the error messages and adding the `$returnurl` session variable but that's for a future question.

```
//LOGIN VALIDATION

if ((empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) or strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') or empty($_POST)) {
    exit("Unauthorized Access");
}

require 'config.php';
require 'functions.php';

if (!empty($_POST) && $_POST['Action']=='login_form') {
    $Return=array('result'=>array(), 'error'=>'');

    $email=safe_input($db, $_POST['Email']);
    $password=safe_input($db, $_POST['Password']);
    $returnUrl=$_SESSION['Return_Url']=$_POST['Return_Url'];

    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $Return['error']="Please enter your email/username.";
    } elseif ($password==='') {
        $Return['error']="Please enter your password.";
    }
    if ($Return['error']!='') {
        output($Return);
    }
    $result=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE email='$email' AND password='".md5($password)."' LIMIT 1");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) {
        $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $Return['result']=$_SESSION['UserData']=array('id'=>$row['id']);
    } else {
        $Return['error']='Email/Password Is Invalid';
    } 
    output($Return);
}

//REGISTRATION VALIDATION

if ((empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) or strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') or empty($_POST)) {
    exit("Unauthorized Access");
}
require 'config.php';
require 'functions.php';

if(!empty($_POST) && $_POST['Action']=='registration_form') {
    $Return=array('result'=>array(), 'error'=>'');

    $name=safe_input($db, $_POST['Name']);
    $email=safe_input($db, $_POST['Email']);
    $password=safe_input($db, $_POST['Password']);
    $returnUrl=$_SESSION['Return_Url']=$_POST['Return_Url'];

    if ($name==='') {
        $Return['error']="Please enter your name.";
    } elseif (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $Return['error']="Please enter your email address.";
    } elseif($password==='') {
        $Return['error']="Please enter a password.";
    }
    if($Return['error']!='') {
        output($Return);
    }

    $result=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) {
        $Return['error']='That email is already registered, please <a href="' . $loginurl . '">Login</a>';
    } else {
        mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO tbl (user_GUID, email, password, entry_date) values(MD5(UUID()), '$email', '".md5($password)."' ,NOW() )");
        $id=mysqli_insert_id($db);
        mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `tbl` (id,name) VALUES('$user_id','$name')");
        $Return['result']=$_SESSION['UserData']=array('id'=>$id);
    }
    output($Return);        
}
```

#### Included Scripts

```
//config.php

session_start();
/*Connection vars here*/
$db=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbase);

//functions.php

function safe_input($db, $data) {
  return htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($data)));
}
function output($Return=array()) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    exit(json_encode($Return));
}
```

#### Error Received

```
mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user...
```

Yes, I know it's been a common issue and the error speaks for itself, but I don't understand why I would get this error when connecting with the same details in a different script has no problem.

As a side note, if someone could tell me what the deal is with that line at the top of both scripts. I looked around the web and found that it deals with ajax but I'm not submitting with ajax (for now, at least). Do I need that line or is it harmless and can stay for when I do use ajax?

As stated, I didn't write this code, only the login/registration forms, so I'm not entirely sure of how it works. I understand the mechanics like testing the data and checking for/adding it in the database. Anything, you can help me with would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is essentially off topic. Such multiple question posts are not allowed by the rules. Edit your post and leave only one question in it

Comment: What exact error you do get? $host, $user, $pass, $dbase do not seem to be defined anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant to provide the error in the question. After looking it up, I see it's become a common issue. I'm guessing it has to do with the mysqli switch-over. I get the access denied error: `Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user...` but I don't see why because connecting in any other script works just fine. And the connect vars are in the config.php file.

Comment: Now it's time to open your eyes. if it says Access denied for user, it means that connect vars are incorrect.

Comment: There it is, the same answer I've seen everywhere I looked. A.) That was the first thing I checked. B.) Besides that, the same vars work outside this script

Comment: Whatever. you see, we can do very little here anyway. Do you agree?

Comment: I was wondering if maybe my scripts aren't coded right since I just found them on the web. I understand only I can do anything about potential incorrect connection vars